High CPU utilization, high port numbers, and high memory usage by configd on macbook pro using 3rd-party battery
I recently replaced old batter on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015 on Monterey) with a battery from iFixit.
After the replacement, I noticed that configd process will take up high CPU utilization (> 100%), and number of ports and memory used keep going up (indicating memory leak?) ONLY WHEN ON battery power. If I connect the laptop to a power source, the issue goes away (top doesn't register configd anywhere near top). I contacted iFixit, and they sent me a replacement battery just in case the battery could be an issue, but the issue remains with new battery.
I've searched the internet forums left and right, and it seems to be an known issue for folks using 3rd-party batteries, but there is no clear answer on what's causing it and how it could be fixed.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Do you see any log items from configd in the Console utility? Can you use Activity Monitor to sample the configd process to see what it's doing when it's so busy? And maybe the non-battery/non-busy case for comparison? These things may give us clues as to what's going on.
Configd is mostly about getting your networking stuff  (network interfaces, VPN, DNS settings) set up correctly. Off the top of my head, I can't think how  running on battery vs. plugged into power might affect that.
Do you notice any networking problems while running on battery?
